# Eigenvectors of Adjoint Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ where $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$. Furthermore, let $v, w \in V$ such that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ (i.e. $Tv = \lambda v$). It follows that

$$
\left<Tv, w\right> = \left<\lambda v, w\right> = \left<v, \overline{\lambda}w\right>
$$

since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $\overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*$. Furthermore, by the definition of adjoint operators,

$$
\left<Tv, w\right> = \left<v, T^*w\right>
$$
These two equalities imply that

$$
\left< v, T^*w\right> = \left<v, \overline{\lambda}w\right>
$$

for any choice of $w \in V$. This implies that any vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T^*$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$. However, this is clearly not true. Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Note that all equations hold only for that $v$, which is not arbitrary.

Comment: Indeed, on John's comment, the last equality you have written implies that $\langle v, T^*w - \overline{\lambda}w \rangle = 0$. This simply says that $v$ is orthogonal to $T^*w - \overline{\lambda}w$. To say that $w$ is an eigenvector of $T$, you would need to use the non-degeneracy of the inner product.

Answer (score 2):

The error was pointed out in the comments by John and Mitchell Faulk. Although it's true that

$$\left(\forall v\in V \ \langle v, T^*w\rangle = \left\langle v, \overline{\lambda}w\right\rangle \right)\implies T^*w = \bar \lambda w $$

in the post the equality on the left was shown only for a specific $v$. This does not imply $T^*w = \bar \lambda w$, but only that $T^*w - \bar \lambda w$ is orthogonal to $v$.